# How to search string references in specified location?

Tags: string, bash, shell, grep, find-occurrences

I'm trying to find the occurence of elements list(from a text file) in a directory.

Below is the Bash code I'm using ,but I'm unable to get the output of grep command on to console.

```
!/bin/bash
FILENAME=$1
count=0
while read LINE
do
  let count++
  echo "$count $LINE"
  grep -r $LINE /home/user/vaishnavi
done < $FILENAME

echo -e "\nTotal $count Lines read"
```

Output:

```
1 ASK
2 TELL 
3 ORDER 
4 NUMBER 
5 SIZE 
6 BASKET 
7 FRUIT 
8 VEGGIES

Total 8 Lines read
```

I'm getting only the list of elements but not their occurences in the specified location.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: use double quote `"$LINE"` in `grep` command.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .But the output is not varying,it is still not showing me the grep results.

Comment: Can you give us an example of input files and of the desired result?

Comment: @vdavid here is the input file i.e. List.txt
ASK
TELL 
ORDER 
NUMBER 
SIZE 
BASKET 
FRUIT 
VEGGIES
Output should be like:

1 ASK 
It's refernces are (should display all "ASK" references in the specified Path)
/home/user/shared/datafeed/etc/fields.xml:  <Field name="ASK" id="10468" type="3" encoding="1" />
Binary file /home/user/shared/bin/x86_win32sMTd.lib matches
Binary file /home/user/bin/x86_win32sMTd.lib matches
Likewise it should display all the references of elements present in List.txt in the same order specified in Txt file.

Comment: @Vaishanavi Then your code looks fine. The only thing I see is that you want to reach files such as /home/user/shared/datafeed/etc/fields.xml but your `grep` command searches /home/user/vaishnavi, which is not a parent folder. If this is your issue, try `grep -r "$LINE" /home/user/shared`

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the result of the grep, for example:

```
echo $(grep -r $LINE /home/user/vaishnavi)
```

Comment: But this giving me  output as
1 ASK

2 TELL

.
.
But not the grep results.